# Reference must be on the active sheet error

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a `reference must be on the active sheet error` on the last line.

```
For Each ws In tabArr()

With ws

    Select Case .Name
        Case "Summary"
            area = "PRNSUMMARY"
            title = "$1:$9"
        Case "Monthly CC Sum"
            area = "PRNMONTHLYCCSUM"
            title = "$2:$16"
        Case .Name = "Div Sal Sum"
            area = "PRNDIVSALSUM"
            title = ""
        Case .Name = "CC Sal Sum"
            area = "PRNCCSALSUM"
            title = "$2:$16"
    End Select

    With .PageSetup
        .PrintArea = area '<----error here
```

I have tried by creating a `worksheet` object.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each e In tabArr()

Set ws = e
Debug.Print ws.Name
With ws
...
```

but still failed :/ The really odd thing is, it prints the first worksheet. Only fails on second.

Comment: Check to see if the named range that you are setting is scoped to a different worksheet. For example, if a named range (`Area1`) is set to `Sheet1!A1:10`, you can't type `Sheets("Sheet2").PageSetup.PrintArea = "Area1"`

Comment: It's not. This was all working perfectly before.

Comment: Perfectly before what?

Comment: In the first 2 `Case`s you have a literal string. In the 3rd and 4th `Case`s you have `.Name = literal`. Was that intentional?

Comment: @TimWilliams [looooong story](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129856/print-worksheets-depending-on-checkbox-slower-than-before#129859). Doubt anyone would care to follow XD

Comment: Yep. Alive and well. Busy...  Contract work, job, family, had to refocus.. I'll be around/back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first 2 `Case` statements you have a literal string. In the 3rd and 4th `Case` statements you have `.Name = literal`

Answer (score 1):

Obviously too late but I came up with a generic repeatable example to recreate the error.

Basically looking at global vs local scope named ranges.  Recreated the error if the named range referred to the wrong sheet or if the sheet specific named range was local to the wrong sheet.

Obviously not the issue but thought I would share anyway.

```
Sub test1()

'Everything declared for sheet2 works fine
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Print_Scope_Global", RefersTo:="=Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Names.Add Name:="Print_Scope_Sheet", RefersTo:="=Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1"

pArea = "Print_Scope_Sheet"
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    With .PageSetup
        .PrintArea = pArea
    End With
End With
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    With .PageSetup
        .PrintArea = pArea
    End With
End With

pArea = "Print_Scope_Global"
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    With .PageSetup
        .PrintArea = pArea
    End With
End With
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    With .PageSetup
        .PrintArea = pArea
    End With
End With


End Sub

Sub test2()

'Named range refers to wrong sheet
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Print_Scope_Global", RefersTo:="=Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Names.Add Name:="Print_Scope_Sheet", RefersTo:="=Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1"

pArea = "Print_Scope_Sheet"
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    With .PageSetup
        .PrintArea = pArea
    End With
End With
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    With .PageSetup
        .PrintArea = pArea
    End With
End With

pArea = "Print_Scope_Global"
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    With .PageSetup
        .PrintArea = pArea
    End With
End With
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    With .PageSetup
        .PrintArea = pArea
    End With
End With


End Sub

Sub test3()

'Name range is local to the wrong sheet
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Names.Add Name:="Print_Scope_Sheet", RefersTo:="=Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1"

pArea = "Print_Scope_Sheet"
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    With .PageSetup
        .PrintArea = pArea
    End With
End With
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    With .PageSetup
        .PrintArea = pArea
    End With
End With

End Sub
```